# SQL update statement to sum column in one table, then add the total to a different column/table

Tags: sql, join, select, sum

Evening all, hoping for some pointers with an SQL Server query if possible.

I have two tables in a database, example as follows:

```
PostedTran 
PostedTranID    AccountID   PeriodID    Value   TransactionDate 
1               100         120         100     2019-01-01
2               100         120         200     2020-01-01
3               100         130         300     2021-01-01
4               101         120         400     2020-01-01
5               101         130         500     2021-01-01

PeriodValue
PeriodValueID   AccountID   PeriodID    ActualValue
10              100         120         500
11              101         120         600
```

I have a mismatch in the two tables, and I'm failing miserably in my attempts. From the PostedTran table, I'm trying to select all transaction lines dated before 2021-01-01, then sum the Value for each AccountID from the results. I then need to add that value to the existing ActualValue in the PeriodValue table.

So, in the above example, the ActualValue on PeriodValueID 10 will update to 800, and 11 to 1000. The PeriodID in this example is constant and will always be 120.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is your RDBMS?

Comment: Hmm, looks suspicious to me... `PeriodValue.ActualValue` isn't meant to hold the sum of `PostedTran.Value`? If so drop the column `PeriodValue.ActualValue` or actually the whole table `PeriodValue`. All they do is storing redundant data which is a bad thing as it can lead to inconsistencies. Instead query the sum if you need it. For convenience you can create a view that does that.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you ask. I haven't included `PeriodId` in the correlation as you did not specify it in your description, however you can just include it if it's required.

```
update pv set pv.ActualValue=pv.ActualValue + t.Value
from PeriodValue pv
cross apply (
    select Sum(value) value
    from PostedTran pt
    where pt.AccountId=pv.AccountId and pt.TransactionDate <'20210101'
)t
```

Answer (score 0):

Since RDMS not mentioned, pseudo-sql looks like:

```
with DataSum as
(
select AccountID, PeriodID, sum(Value) as TotalValue
from PostedTran 
where TransactionDate<'1/1/2021'
group by AccountID, PeriodID
)
update PeriodValue set ActualValue = ActualValue + ds.TotalVaue
from PeriodValue pv inner join DataSum ds
on pv.accountid=ds.accountid and pv.periodid=ds.periodid
```